# VSCode go Launch configs ignored in tests

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

It seems go test is ignoring the selected launch config, what's the correct way to switch between different settings (mostly build tags) to run tests ?

We've got different files gated by different tags, and I don't see any way of running the tests for these tags in VSCode right now, clicking the various tests buttons just defaults to the wrong build tags and it ends up erroring because all the tests files are excluded.

Thanks